# ArangoDB, Java and Modules

Tags: java, arangodb, arangodb-java

I am relatively new to Java, use Java v11, have set up my project with modules and want to add the module "jackson.dataformat.velocypack". But both modules

```
modules-info.java:
[…]
requires arangodb.java.driver;
requires jackson.dataformat.velocypack;
[…]
```

use "com.arangodb". So my project can't no longer be compiled. Unfortunately I have no idea how to solve this. Can anybody give me an idea...

Thank you very much.

Manu

Comment: Updating to `com.arangodb:jackson.dataformat.velocypack:0.2.0` should solve the problem.